# AWS: Accessing a secret in another account from a Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have 2 accounts: services and training. In the training account, I have a Lambda that needs to read a secret stored in the services account. I've followed the instructions in [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secrets-manager-share-between-accounts/) article to set up roles and permissions. I then confirmed that I could read the secret using the AWS CLI as follows:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:SERVICES:secret:/dev/camp/event_api_secret-YvlRG9 --profile events --region us-east-2
```

The events profile is configured to assume the events-dispatcher role in the training account. This command successfully returned the secret confirming that the events-dispatcher role in the training account can indeed access the secret in the services account.

The camp-event-dispatcher Lambda in the training account is configured with the events-dispatcher role as its execution role. The handler code is:

```
import {GetSecretValueCommand, SecretsManagerClient} from "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager";

const client = new SecretsManagerClient({region: process.env.AWS_REGION});
// TODO: Pass secret ID in environment variable
const command = new GetSecretValueCommand({SecretId: 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:SERVICES:secret:/dev/camp/event_api_secret-YvlRG9'});
const response = await client.send(command);
const secretValue = response.SecretString;

exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
  console.log(`SECRET value = ${secretValue}`);
  console.log("EVENT: \n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))
  return context.logStreamName
}
```

The call to get the secret fails with the following error:

> User:
> arn:aws:sts::TRAINING:assumed-role/camp-event-dispatcher/event_dispatcher
> is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on
> resource:
> arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:SERVICES:secret:/dev/camp/event_api_secret-YvlRG9
> because no resource-based policy allows the
> secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action

Edit: here is the resource based policy on the secret. Note that this is much more permissive than I'll actually use in production and I also added the assumed role principal which was reported in the error although I don't think I should have to do that.

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::TRAINING:role/event-dispatcher"
    },
    "Action" : "secretsmanager:*",
    "Resource" : "*"
  }, {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : "arn:aws:sts::TRAINING:assumed-role/camp-event-dispatcher/event_dispatcher"
    },
    "Action" : "secretsmanager:*",
    "Resource" : "*"
  } ]
}
```

Edit: Here is the policy on the event-dispatcher role in the TRAINING account.  This is the lambda's execution role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:SERVICES:secret:/dev/camp/event_api_secret-YvlRG9"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:SERVICES:key/c08bd5e6-4c65-41b0-989e-e1e8db0cad83"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can You access the secret in the CLI? I mean use the TRAINING Account credentials and call the SecretManager cli command to get the SERVICES secret. I would test this first.
My second idea is that You maybe need to assume the role in the lambda

Comment: @ExceptionNotThrownException, yes you'll see in my post that using the CLI to confirm access by the role was the first thing I did

Comment: can you share the resource based policy of the secret in your question?

Comment: @Paolo, I've updated the post with the resource based policy on the secret

Comment: BTW.  Here's another article that describes both approaches we've been discussing: the "assume role" approach and the "resource based policy" approach: https://itarunkumar.medium.com/securely-access-aws-secrets-manager-across-different-aws-accounts-3b0821f4e2e1

Comment: I've tried using the "assume role" approach and I'm getting a similar error although now the error is that there is no identity-based policy (as opposed to resource-based policy) that allows secretsmanager:GetSecretValue.  I even tried just listing the secrets with ListSecretsCommand, but got the same error. @Paolo, could you repost the blog article about this? It looks like you deleted your previous answer with that information.

Comment: Can you confirm that the resource policy actually has the account numbers in it and not `TRAINING` ?

Comment: @Paolo, yes my code has the account number. I believe I found the source of the problem. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem here came down to a bug in my lambda code. The secret I was trying to access is in a different region than the lambda. So this line:

```
const client = new SecretsManagerClient({region: process.env.AWS_REGION});
```

should have been:

```
const client = new SecretsManagerClient({region: "region_where_the_secret_lives});
```

I finally figured this out (after banging my head against the wall for a bit longer) when the both the "resource based" and "assume role" approaches didn't work. Now that I'm specifying the correct region, the "assume role" approach works.  I'm sure the "resource based" approach would also would also work now.

Thanks everyone for your help and advice.